# Window scrolling down when there are anchor links

Tags: javascript, anchor

I have got an issue with anchors links / deep linking. I have got few tabs in a page with ids such as `tab1`, `tab2`. When I hit the URL with anchor = **"#tab2"** I can select the right tab through JavaScript but the window scrolls down.

I tried to change the `window.location.hash` on-the-fly and delete the id name but still the page  is scrolled down. I even tried to invoke `$(window).scrollTop(0)` function but it doesn't work.

Any help on it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like you want to do only your function in javascript and not go to link.
Then add return false; to your function.

```
function test()
{
  alert('clicked');
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Well, I understand it, look at this http://jsfiddle.net/qQGpz/ isn't that you want? Have you tried with return false ?

Comment: sorry mate you are off track..my issue is that when I hit directly a page with anchor link, the window scrolls down to the object with that id, and I want to prevent that to happen.."Return false" in that case doesn't work. thanks anyway